# Improving Project Workflow on GitHub

Tags: git, github, travis-ci

I am currently working on an open source cloud project. The project has its repository on GitHub which isn't in my control.
I have my own forked repository and I have integrated the Travis CI on it to automatically build my code and run my test cases. You need a number of files, such as the .travis.yml file, which you need to push on GitHub to trigger Travis. I am using a Rakefile to run my unit tests.

The problem is that the main repository of the project isn't under my control and the owners of the repository do not want to configure Travis CI with it. Hence if I generate a pull request, I need to make sure that none of my test files (For e.g. .travis.yml or Rakefile) make it along the pull request. Of course I could delete those files but they would still show up in the commit history and that is exactly what I am trying to avoid. I do not want any trace of Travis CI reaching the main repository whenever a pull request is generated.

To make this happen, the following workflow was agreed upon:

```
 1. Fork project repository in your own GitHub account.
 2. Clone it in your local computer. Set up the main repository as your upstream 
    repository.
 3. Create a testing branch from the master branch and push it on origin (your account).
 4. Before you start working on a new feature, pull the latest code from the upstream 
    repository into both the master as well as the testing branch.
 5. Add the .travis.yml and other test files that you need to activate Travis CI in the 
    testing branch and once again push to origin.
 6. Create a feature branch from the master branch. 
 7. Do all your work on the feature branch. Write code, run tests.
 8. When feature is ready, take the latest code pull from the upstream repo. 
    Resolve any merge conflicts that happen.
 9. Generate Peer Reviews.
10. [Peer Reviews Passed] Merge feature branch into the testing branch.
11. Push the testing branch on origin. This will activate Travis CI
12. [Travis Passed] Generate Pull Request. Your work is done.
13. [Travis Failed] Travis CI has failed your tests. Repeat Step 7.
```

To visualize this, take a look at the following diagram

=> [Project Workflow Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bMIiS.jpg)

My question is can any help me improve this workflow? As you can see, merging the code each time into the testing branch to trigger Travis CI is a lot of overhead.